# underscore js backbone js two templates

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to handle two templates in backbone js. How do I go about doing so? I want to pass in the json for the models in the template?

I have the following:

```
            var json = model.toJSON(), json2 = model2.toJSON();

            that.$el.html(_.template(tmpl, json, json2));
```

but that does not allow me to get the fields from the second json in underscore.

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax would be

```
var data = {
    modelOne: model.toJSON(),
    modelTwo: model2.toJSON()
}

that.$el.html(_.template(tmpl, data));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the models don't mixed inside template, You can do  that : need to create new template for second model, and add to necessary address

```
var addressToSecondModel = $(that.$el).find("address");
addressToSecondModel.html(_.template(tmpl2, json2));
```